# Is Cassandra a good choice for this kind of time series data vs sql server?

Tags: cassandra

Consider this scenario, we collect financial market data (e.g. price of fund) and store it in a sql table.

Normally Fund prices at most once a day, so the table can be:

```
FundId  Date       Price1     Price2
```

When we want some data, a simple query will do:

```
select Date, Price1, Price2 from FundPriceTable where Date between  XX and XX
```

However, as we gathered more and more data, the above query performance began to go down. We tried re-indexing and refresh stats. The problem is that when we retrieve vast amount of data (e.g. get 10 year history for 1000 fund), it can take quite a while.

I am wondering for this scenario (no join at all), will system like Cassandra show any performance benefit (assume same hardware)?

I tried to find some benchmark articles between Cassandra and sql server for time series, unfortunately didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your schema. The performance boost depends on your partition key. In your example:
You can split your data by day or month. This example is spitted by month:

```
fundPricesByDay (month int, timestamp timestamp, productId text, Price1 float, Price2, PRIMARY KEY(month, timestamp, productId))
```

If you need all data between the first and third month, you can execute 3 queries:

```
select * from fundPricesByDay where month = 1 AND timestamp > 60000;
select * from fundPricesByDay where month = 2;
select * from fundPricesByDay where month = 3 AND timestamp < 99999;
```

With these three queries you will get all data between timestamp 60000 and 99999. But you execute all queries on different vNodes. This means each node has to handle fewer rows than sql. It makes a performance boost. Read a bit more about how Cassandra works and you will understand how you can boost your tables.

You ask explicitly for the same hardware. Maybe there's no performance boost. Simply benchmark it. But Cassandra will definitely win in the combination of scalability and performance. SQL has its limit (depends on the hardware, clustering is possible but complicated to implement and has also its limitations), Cassandra does not have this limitations in scalability and performance. (or better: It's really difficult to hit a limit when you have a good schema.)

Comment: Thanks, I am doing some initial research, so to setup as you said will take quite some time. For the three queries you mentioned, will it run concurrently automatically or in my code I need to create multiple threads to do it?

Comment: Depends on your language but generally you can querying all code async. I worked with the scala, php and nodejs driver and in all drivers is a async option.